# Setted wireless interface but captures ethernet data

Tags: c, linux, pcap, packet-sniffers, sniffing

I am making a sniffer using libpcap and I am getting some weird behavior.
I don't know much about network, for it I am making the sniffer to learn how network really works.

Before I run the sniffer, I type `ifconfig` on terminal, and it returns:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 44:87:fc:ec:63:08  
          endereço inet6: fe80::4687:fcff:feec:6308/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCASTMULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          RX packets:38398 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28661 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:2
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:24620500 (23.4 MiB)  TX bytes:6922586 (6.6 MiB)
          IRQ:42 

lo        Link encap:Loopback Local  
          inet end.: 127.0.0.1  Masc:255.0.0.0
          endereço inet6: ::1/128 Escopo:Máquina
          UP LOOPBACKRUNNING  MTU:16436  Métrica:1
          RX packets:294 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:294 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:18540 (18.1 KiB)  TX bytes:18540 (18.1 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 00:c1:40:67:04:30  
          inet end.: 192.168.0.102  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::2c1:40ff:fe67:430/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCASTRUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          RX packets:2115 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2033 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:947310 (925.1 KiB)  TX bytes:571860 (558.4 KiB)
```

I took off the ethernet cable, so, the eth0 interface has no ip and will not work if I use it on my sniffer.

Thus, I pass the wireless network interface as parameter to the program on terminal.

```
#./sniffer wlan0
```

And a snippet code:

```
pcap_t* handler = NULL; 

handler = pcap_open_live(argv[1], 65535, 1, 1000, errbuf);

if((datalink_value = pcap_datalink(handler)) == DLT_EN10MB)
    printf("ETHERNET\n");
else if (datalink_value == DLT_IEEE802_11)
    printf("WIRELESS\n");
```

The output is `ETHERNET`.

Why this is occurring and how can I fix it ? The device converts it into ethernet ? Or this is a kernel behavior ?
I still don't know if the problem is my code or if I don't know well about how network and protocol works.

The wireless device that I am using is: Mini USB 150Mbps 802.11n/g/b wifi Adapter Comfast WU720N

Thanks.

Comment: Because the encapsulation is always encap:Ethernet

Comment: @LPs This will always occur on wireless network ? I mean, this is a rule ? Thanks.

Comment: @Guy Harris answered you very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, you need to capture in monitor mode in order to get 802.11 headers.  If the adapter isn't in monitor mode, you will only get data frames, not management or control frames, and the 802.11 header will be turned into a fake Ethernet header by the kernel and the packet will be provided with that header.

Newer versions of libpcap have an API to request monitor mode, but, on Linux, that API only works well if libpcap was built with support for libnl.  You could try using the API (use `pcap_create()`, followed by calls to set capture options, followed by `pcap_activate()`, to open the device; one of those calls should be `pcap_set_rfmon()` to set monitor mode).  If that doesn't work, you'd have to use airmon-ng to turn on monitor mode; see [this part of the Wireshark Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN?highlight=%28airmon-ng%29#Linux) for information on how to do that.